# WebServices not working after upgrading from VS 2012 to VS 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Edit (7-17-2014) It's been four days since I posted this question and I am still stumped. Can anyone offer suggestions or places where I can start looking? Based on what I've learned so far, it seems possibly VS 2013 is looking in a different location than VS 2012...could that be it...I need to modify my web service path?

I created a web application in VS 2012, that uses web services. Everything works as it should. I just upgraded to VS 2013 and now my web services gives an error.

When I check the result object, in the resultText, I see the error:

```
No web service found at: /testserver/WebServices.asmx
```

Not sure how to approach this since it works in VS 2012. Can someone help?

Thank you.

**WebServices.asmx** file:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/WebServices.cs" 
    Class="WebServices.Services" %>
```

`WebServices.cs` Signature:

```
namespace WebServices
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://MyCompanyInhouseserver.com/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ToolboxItem(false)]
    [ScriptService]
    public class Services : WebService
    {
        Code...
    }
}
```

Ajax: (Added this in case it is a coding issue that got exposed in VS 2013. Code breaks in the complete: section.)

```
var pageUrl = "/testserver/WebServices.asmx";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: pageUrl + "/ValidateLogin",
            data: "{'username': '" + self.username() + "', 'password': '" + self.password() + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {

            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            },
            complete: function (result) {
                if (result.responseJSON.d != null && result.responseJSON.d.UserId > 0) {
                    $(window.location).attr('href', 'startproject.aspx');
                } else {
                    self.loginError("Invalid username/password");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: where are you hosting your web service? IIS, VS integraded WebServer, IIS Express? Can you open the web service url with a browser? With ASP.Net web services you should at least see some sort of default site.

Comment: Is this a web site "project" (File->New Web Site), or a web application project (File->New Project)?

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek I am hosting the web service using VS integrated Web Server and I can open it in a browser and run all the exposed methods I have created.

Comment: @JohnSaunders This is a web application project. I used this site [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/create-simple-web-service-in-visual-studio-2008-2010-2012/) as an example when I created the project in VS 2012.

Comment: Is testserver your server name? Then the URL would be `/WebServices.asmx`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders...even better than the answer I selected. That way, I don't have to worry about creating a virtual directory while I am developing it on my laptop. Would like to know why it originally worked in VS 2012 and not in VS 2013 though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the web project's properties in visual studio and go to the `Web` section. Determine if you are using `Local IIS` which will require you to `Create a Virtual Directory` as well as have IIS installed. If you have `IIS Express` you will also need to create a virtual directory; but note that off of the localhost is a port number, you may need to adjust your url to that port number as well as local host for testing purposes after you build and run the project.

Comment: I am using VS integrated web server. I should not have to create a virtual directory when I am only running in VS 2013 should I?

Comment: @Wannabe I don't believe you have to when using the integrated server. Try out IIS Express for different results. Also try adding the product name after localhost...I have found that sometimes it is requested.

Comment: It worked to change to IIS Express and creating a virtual directory. Then I was able to run the application no matter which version of VS I am using. Thanks.